# Show navbar-nav horizontally in mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

The code below shows horizontally in normal desktop view. However, on mobile screen, it shows vertically.

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
    </ul>
```

Web View: 
Link 1    Link 2

Mobile View:

Link 1

Link 2

I want to show the Mobile view horizontally. Trying to find the right css but couldn't find it after spending hours on it. Could someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
float: left !important;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
margin-right: -15px !important;
}

.navbar-right {
float: right!important;
}
```

**<kbd>[Check This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/8384qz7m/)</kbd>**

Comment: i used another method but this works too. thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

**Bootstrap 4**

Wrapping your code with `nav` and `navbar-expand` class makes the trick.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item pl-2">Link 1</li>
            <li class="nav-item pl-2">Link 2</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navbar Fixed Top would be what you're looking for

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: This is for mobile collapse and toggle. i'm not looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that there just isn't space in mobile view to show the two links side by side. You could try some media queries to target specific resolutions for mobile (and other views - investigate something like Bootstrap3 to see common break points).

Try this, it will make each link half the screen width and so they should sit side by side, assuming the rest of your CSS is ensuring that there is no list style etc:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

You should probably post your CSS code for us to be able to help a little more too.

Comment: Space is not the problem since it shows horizontally when i use the class="list-inline". It becomes vertical when i use the class="nav navbar-nav" or even class="list-inline nav navbar-nav". Also, i'm using bootstrap3, there's no css code added.

Comment: From the Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar):

_The navbar collapses into its **vertical mobile view** when the viewport is narrower than @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen)._

So basically if you don't want this to happen, find another way of displaying your list I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Use This 
HTML

```
<div id="nav-btn">Button</div>
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>

        <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 1.1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 1.2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 1.3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 1.4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>

        <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 2.1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 2.2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 2.3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 2.4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>

        <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 3.1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 3.2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 3.3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 3.4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>

        <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 4.1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 4.2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 4.3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 4.4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>

        <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 5.1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 5.2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 5.3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 5.4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>

        <div class="mobnav-subarrow"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 6.1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 6.2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 6.3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 6.4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#nav-btn {
    display: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-subarrow {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #nav-btn {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav-subarrow {
        display: block;
        background-color: #0f3975;
        opacity: .3;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        height: 20px;
        width: 30px;
        background-position: top left!important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    }
    .sf-menu {
        width: 100%!important;
        display: none;
    }
    .sf-menu.xactive {
        display: block!important;
    }
    .sf-menu li {
        float: none!important;
        display: block!important;
        width: 100%!important;
    }
    .sf-menu li a {
        float: none!important;
    }
    .sf-menu ul {
        position:static!important;
        display: none!important;
    }
    .xpopdrop ul {
        display: block!important;
    }
}
```

JS

```
$('#nav-btn').click(

function () {
    $('.sf-menu').toggleClass("xactive");
});



$('.nav-subarrow').click(

function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("xpopdrop");
});
```

Comment: Is this bootstrap? and i'm not using JQuery. Thank you though.